# Angular global error handler not seeing error instanceof TimeoutError

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs

In a service making api calls, I'm forcing a timeout to test the behavior of a global error handler. The service can see in its catchError block that it receives a TimeoutError. It rethrows the error so the global error handler can handle it, but then the error is seen as an Error but not a TimeoutError. Is this by design? I'd like to know the error type in the global error handler by checking instanceof.

Using Angular 8.2.14, rxjs 6.4.0.

The code in the service is like this:

```
  init$(objName: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.apiQueryService.getDataObj1$(objName)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(
          dataObj1 => this.apiQueryService.getDataObj2$(this.handleDataObj1(dataObj1))),
        map(dataObj2 => this.handleDataObj2(dataObj2)),
        timeout(5),                                // this forces a quick timeout
        catchError(e => {
          console.log('err in init$', e);          // "err in init$ TimeoutErrorImpl {message: "Timeout has occurred", name: "TimeoutError"}"
          console.log(e instanceof TimeoutError);  // true
          console.log(e instanceof Error);         // true
          if (e instanceof TimeoutError) {
            // return throwError(e);
            throw e;
          }
          return of(false);
        })
      );
  }
```

The global error handler is like this:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { TimeoutError } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private zone: NgZone) { }

  handleError(error: any): void {
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);

    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      console.error('Backend returned status code:', error.status);
      console.error('Response body:', error.message);
    } else {
      console.error('An error occurred:');
      console.log(error instanceof TimeoutError);    // false
      console.log(error instanceof Error);           // true
      console.log( error.name );                     // Error
      console.log( error.message );                  // Uncaught (in promise): Timeout has occurred
    }

    this.zone.run(() => {router.navigate(['error'])});
  }
}
```

Edit: Per the comment by @DeborahK, I changed "return throwError(e)" to "throw e" and I'm seeing the same behavior. That is, the Error that is of instance TimeoutError in the service is just of Error when the error handler receives it.

It may be worth noting that if I remove the whole catchError block from the service, the error handler still doesn't recognize it as instanceof TimeoutError.

Comment: `throwError` is *not* the same as new Error(). `throwError` is a function that returns an Observable that immediately errs out. This article may clarify: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/throwerror-is-not-throw-error-ad6c76c53377

Comment: Facing exact same problem- Custom errors lose their type when they get to my global ErrorHandler

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your errorHandler method:

```
    const error = err.rejection ? err.rejection : err;
```

@theactiveactor, this works for me..

like

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private zone: NgZone) { }

  handleError(err: any): void {
    // THIS LINE DOES THE MAGIC
    const error = err.rejection ? err.rejection : err;

    const router = this.injector.get(Router);

    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      console.error('Backend returned status code:', error.status);
      console.error('Response body:', error.message);
    } else {
      console.error('An error occurred:');
      console.log(error instanceof TimeoutError);    // false
      console.log(error instanceof Error);           // true
      console.log( error.name );                     // Error
      console.log( error.message );                  // Uncaught (in promise): Timeout has occurred
    }

    this.zone.run(() => {router.navigate(['error'])});
  }
}
```